# Magento 2: Remove price change from custom option dropdown in magento 2.2.3

Tags: product, custom-options, magento2.2.3

Is there a way of removing the price change (e.g. the string '+$10.00' or '+$15.00') from after the option name in a custom option dropdown list?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.